# Slow to Load GridView

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, gridview

I have a GridView that loads some images. I put a log method on the GetView (on the Adapter class) and I realized that this method is executed more times than the number of images. 
A thread is executed to get the image on the GetView.
I think that if the GetView was only called once for each image, the Grid would load faster. Am I correct? Is there a way of doing that?

This is my GetView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    ViewHolder view;
    PMCategory category = categoriesArray.get(position);

    RewardImageLazyLoadingThread rewardImageLazyLoader = new RewardImageLazyLoadingThread();
    if (layout == null) {
        layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.reward_item_image, parent, false);
        view = new ViewHolder();
        view.reward_imageView = (ImageView) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.reward_image);

        layout.setTag(view);
    } else {
        view = (ViewHolder) layout.getTag();
    }

    if (position > CurrPosition) //To throw the thread only once for each image
     {
        positionAtual = position;
        rewardImageLazyLoader.setProperties(category.id, view);
        rewardImageLazyLoader.execute();

    }
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: I still don't know why that happend, but to improve the app performance I decided to check if it was the first time that GetView() was executed or not.